# Chaining http requests using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, es6-promise

In my function "reqHandler" I collect form data and pass it into my http.request. To chain requests, I declared a Promise and .then handler. Problem is that:
1. This is written into console "Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"
2. It seems like .then is not invoked, so no API calls are made.

Code:

```
"use strict";

const http        = require("http");
const qs          = require("querystring");
const fs          = require("fs");
const PORT        = 3000;

let resObject = {};
let hash = "";

const options = {
  hostname: "netology.tomilomark.ru",
  path: "/api/v1/hash",
  method: "post"
};

const reqHandler = (req, res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (req.url === "/") {
      switch (req.method.toLowerCase()) {
        case "get":
          // Browse my form with "Name" and "Surname" inputs
          fs.readFile("./logs/form.html", (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
              reject("Promise rejected");
              return
            }
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':file.length});
            res.write(file);
            res.end();
          });
          break;
        case "post":
          // Collect form data and parse it using querystring
          let body = "";
          req.setEncoding("utf8");
          req.on("data", (data) => {
            body += data;
            if (body.length > 1e6)
              req.connection.destroy();
          });
          req.on("end", () => {
            let post = qs.parse(body);
            console.log(post);
            options.headers = {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "firstname": `${post.firstName}`
            };
            options.body = {
              "lastname": `${post.lastName}`
            };
            // Resolve with "options" object that has headers and body
            resolve(options);
          });
          break;
        default:
          badRequest(res);
      }
    } else {
      notFound(res);
    }
  });
};

reqHandler()
  .then((options) => {
    http.request(options, (res) => {
      let resString = "";
      res.on("data", (data) => {
        resString += data;
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        console.log(resString);
      });
      res.end();
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {throw err});

let badRequest = (res) => {
  res.statusCode = 400;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Bad Request');
};

let notFound = (res) => {
  res.statusCode = 404;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Not Found');
};

const server = http.createServer();
server.on("error", (err) => console.error(err));
server.on("request", reqHandler);
server.on("listening", () => console.log(`Start HTTP on port ${PORT}`));
server.listen(PORT);
```

**Ultimately**, what´s wrong with my promise and .then? **Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: What's the issue you're seeing? Quick suggest. you can use `request-promise` library which is a wrapper around request module

Comment: Instead of testing `if (req.url === "/")` and `case "get" / case "post"`, you should implement a router... `app.get("/"), app.post("/")`, shouldn't you?

Comment: `reqHandler()` expects two parameters, but you call it without arguments.

Comment: @JeremyThille the thing is that I have to use built-in modules and what you suggest is express.js framework

Comment: I wonder why one wouldn't be allowed to use Express when building a Node app, but meh

Comment: @Rowland my code after .then does not work at all, so no requests to API are made. I can use only built-in modules and pure http ;(

Comment: You forget to set `resolve` for your get method. You have just `reject` there. So your get method will never get success. So no then will be called.

Comment: @PeterMader I think that´s the fault, but I don´t get what arguments I should pass into this function. Obviously, just setting them as "req, res" won´t work..

Comment: But it should work. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request.   
`reqHandler(req, res)
  .then((options) => {
    http.request(options, (res) => {`

Comment: The thing is: a promise represents the eventual completion (or failure) of **one** asynchronous operation, and its resulting value. Promises are *not* about reoccurring events.

Comment: @JanNahody writes "req is not defined" ;(

Comment: @PeterMader so how this code should be reorganised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have create a test environment and here you have an abstract version of your source.
Your mistakes was to wrap your promise in a function which pass the req and res parameters and you have to call resolve or reject inside your promise, what have been forgotten on several places.

This source is tested!

```
const http = require('http');

const reqHandler = (req, res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (req.url === "/") {
      switch (req.method.toLowerCase()) {
        case "get":
          console.log('get');
          return resolve('get');
        case "post":
          console.log('post');
          return resolve('post');
        default:
          return resolve('default');
      }
    } else {
      return resolve('some thing else');
    }
  });
};

const myReqHandler = (req, res) => {
    reqHandler(req, res).then(()=> {
        console.log('then reached')
    });
}


const PORT = 8089;
const server = http.createServer();
server.on("error", (err) => console.error(err));
server.on("request", myReqHandler);
server.on("listening", () => console.log(`Start HTTP on port ${PORT}`));
server.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: Adapted your code to my task, no problems with promise and its handlers. Next time I´ll be more careful about resolve & reject..

Thank you!